# how do i know how many columns to put in a truth table

Tags: logic

Oh man i am in so much trouble!
I am in school for my RN and am taking all my classes online. I suck at math to begin with, and then trying to teach myself? = Trouble
current problems are truth tables. how in the world do i know how many columns to make? i have searched the world over and can't find an answer.

example: $(\neg p \wedge  q) \vee \neg q$

ok so i know bc the answer is in the book that there are 6 columns 
$$\neg p, q, \neg p, \neg p \wedge q, \neg q, \text{ and } (\neg p \wedge q) \vee \neg q$$
But how am I supposed to get them?

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange!  The (unfortunate) answer is that it depends and you just have to play with it to figure it out.  For example: if you are trying to find the truth table for $p \vee (q \wedge r)$ there is no reason to have a column for $\neg p$, right?  But if you are trying to find the truth table for $\neg (p \vee q)$ you would probably want a column for $p \vee q$.  On, the other hand, if you want to know how many rows the truth table will need, that is definitely answerable.

Answer (score 3):

Unless your instructor has specific requirements, you put as many as you need.  The only column you **must** have is the one showing the final result.

It's really just like numerical calculation.  Say for example if you have numbers $x,y,z$ and you want to calculate $(2x+y)z-y/x$, then you might do the following: calculate and write down $2x$ then $2x+y$ then $(2x+y)z$ then $y/x$ then $(2x+y)z-y/x$.  So this would be five columns.

On the other hand perhaps you can do $2x$ in your head and write down $2x+y$ straight away.  Then you could leave out the $2x$ column and just write four columns: $2x+y$ then $(2x+y)z$ then $y/x$ then $(2x+y)z-y/x$.  If you are good at mental arithmetic you could maybe get away with even fewer.  It's the same with truth tables, you write down as much or as little as you need.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

A dose of patience and critical thinking to begin with.

Start from the basics and build up.

What you need at first is a column for both $p$ and $q$. From there, how many possible combinations can they form? For example, $p$ = T/F, $q$ = T/F. After you have enough rows for all the possibilities, start working on the next columns. $\neg p$ is easy to calculate if you have $p$. You just have to look at your first two columns when you're doing things like $\neg p \land q$. It's true only when $p$ is false and $q$ is true.

Keep building until you have enough to tackle your big problem.

You can split $(\neg p \lor q) \land \neg q$ into $(\neg p \lor q)$ and $\neg q$. Just look at those two columns, and you can see that your big expression is true when either of those smaller expressions are true.

Just take it slow, analyze. Break big problems down.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the same number of columns as the number of variables.   In this case,  one for p and one for q.  Then build up the proposition on term at a time,  from the inside of the parentheses moving out. I think the next column should be ~p.

Answer (score 1):

There is no fixed way to do it.

1) Write a column for each variable. That make two. Write another for each negation: that's four. Then one for the ∨: that gets evaluated first. Then one for the ∧: that gets evaluated last.

2) You could also  leave space for  a column below each symbol in the formula, except the parentheses. Start with the variables; this would give you two identical columns for q. Then, below the first ¬, write down the values for ¬p, and below the second ¬, the values for ¬q. Then, using the values for ¬p and q, write the values for (¬p∧q) below the ∧. Then, using the values for (¬p∧q) and those for ¬q, evaluate (¬p∧q)∨¬q and write those below the ∨. That's your answer.

You may want to try both and see which way works for you.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do the truth table for a formula $\varphi$ is to use the *formation tree* for that formula, i.e. to follow the process used to build up the formula starting from the *propositional letters* and applying the *formation rules*.

In our example :

> $(\lnot p \land q) \lor \lnot q$

we have two propositional letters : $p$ and $q$ and we have built up the formula using the following steps :

*(i)* apply the rule for $\lnot$ and get : $\lnot q$

*(ii)* apply the rule for $\lnot$ and get : $\lnot p$

*(iii)* apply the rule for $\land$ and get : $(\lnot p \land q)$

*(iv)* apply the rule for $\lor$ and get : $(\lnot p \land q) \lor \lnot q$, and this is our formula.

So, on the LHS of the truth-table we need two columns : one for $p$ and one for $q$.

On the RHS we may have four columns : one for $\lnot q$, one for $\lnot p$, one for $(\lnot p \land q)$ and one for $(\lnot p \land q) \lor \lnot q$.

Of course, we cannot omit the last one, corresponding to the complete formula; we may omit (if we are clever enough with the "calculations") some of the "intermediate" columns (those corresponding to the subformulas), especially the "simple" ones, like those for negation.

Answer (score 1):

For what it is worth, this makes just another version of @David's point.

Suppose you are asked to construct a truth-table for a single wff $C$. Then, the bare bones of what you need to write down are, to the left, a table setting out every possible assignment of values to the propositional variables you find in $C$. (If $C$ contains $n$ different variables, you'll need $n$ columns and $2^n$ rows.) Then, to the right, the column which gives the value of $C$ at each row, corresponding to that assignment of values to the propositional variables.

And that's all you *need*. End of story. (Unless, in very elementary exercises you are explicitly asked to "show your working".)

Anything else you write down (e.g. because $C$ is a bit complicated and you can't yet do the calculation of value in your head) is scratch work -- and you can put it as much or as little of that as you need. Practice mental arithmetic with truth-tables! (NB many textbooks -- including mine -- will tell you about short-cuts for helping you on your way, and for writing down interim results in a computation by writing the values of sub formulae under the connective being evaluated at that point in the computation. Check out a few textbooks.)

You should get used to putting it as little scratch work as possible. That's because at the next step you will be asked to do truth tables not for single wffs but for arguments, to assess the validity of say $A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4 \therefore C$ where there are four premisses. That requires again a table starting on the left with every possible assignment of values to every propositional variable to be found in the inference, and then five more columns, giving the values for the four premisses and the conclusion. You don't want to be cluttering up all that with unnecessary scratch working!